# Chrome V84 certificate valid but "Not Secure"

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, https

Chrome pushed out version **84.0.4147.89** this week and started marking one of our websites as "Not Secure" even though our certificate is valid.

This is only happening on Win7 machines, other browsers are not affected and still working as intended.

Apon reading the release notes for this version they stated to remove TLS1.0  & TLS 1.1 support but we are using TLS1.2 so we shouldnt be affected?

> **Remove TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 TLS (Transport Layer Security)** is the
> protocol which secures HTTPS. It has a long history stretching back to
> the nearly twenty-year-old TLS 1.0 and its even older predecessor,
> SSL. Both TLS 1.0 and 1.1 have a number of weaknesses

> Supporting TLS 1.2 is a prerequisite to avoiding the above problems.
> The TLS working group has deprecated TLS 1.0 and 1.1. Chrome has now
> also deprecated these protocols.

SSL certificate is currently with Lets Encrypt but i have tried a Sertigo SSL. Testing the SSL via **SSLLabs** results in this result.

**Protocols**

```
TLS 1.3     No
TLS 1.2     Yes
TLS 1.1     Yes
TLS 1.0     Yes
SSL 3       No
SSL 2       No
```

**TLS 1.2 (suites in server-preferred order)**

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)  
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)  
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)  
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e) 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027) 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)  
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013) 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9d)
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9c)
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x3d)
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x3c)
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)  
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide the web server SSL/TLS configuration, also provide the ciphers the certificate support, there are also websites that help determine your compatibility rating surrounding SSL/TLS have you used one of those?  Edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, please see updated question

Comment: So the reason you are getting the warning is due to the fact your website is allowing TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 clients.  You should make the necessary adjustments to disallow those clients.  There are known exploits, that allow a client to downgrade their connection to TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 this allowing them to use known vulnerabilities with TLS 1.0 and 1.1;  **honestly the only secure TLS version is 1.3**. Since all major browsers support it enabling that would solve potential problems

Comment: Thanks for the advise @Ramhound, ill make the changes out of hours tonight and advise how it goes